# message.getContent() method returns the body in a single line, if trying to read any mail coming from yahoomail in javax.mail api

Tags: jakarta-mail

Please find the complete content.

```
    Received: from PS1PR01MB0987.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com (10.165.64.153) by
     KL1PR01MB0984.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com (10.164.231.26) with Microsoft
     SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
     cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id 15.1.947.12 via Mailbox
     Transport; Wed, 8 Mar 2017 11:41:21 +0000
    Received: from SG2PR01CA0017.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com (10.165.9.155) by
     PS1PR01MB0987.apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com (10.165.64.153) with Microsoft
     SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
     cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id 15.1.947.12; Wed, 8 Mar
     2017 11:41:17 +0000
    Received: from SG2APC01FT061.eop-APC01.prod.protection.outlook.com
     (2a01:111:f400:7ebe::202) by SG2PR01CA0017.outlook.office365.com
     (2a01:111:e400:79a6::27) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2,
     cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id 15.1.961.14 via
     Frontend Transport; Wed, 8 Mar 2017 11:41:17 +0000
    Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 98.136.216.141)
     smtp.mailfrom=yahoo.com; affineanalytics.com; dkim=pass (signature was
     verified) header.d=yahoo.com;affineanalytics.com; dmarc=pass action=none
     header.from=yahoo.com;
    Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of yahoo.com designates
     98.136.216.141 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;
     client-ip=98.136.216.141; helo=nm34-vm2.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com;
    Received: from nm34-vm2.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com (98.136.216.141) by
     SG2APC01FT061.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.251.65) with Microsoft SMTP
     Server (version=TLS1_0, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384) id
     15.1.933.11 via Frontend Transport; Wed, 8 Mar 2017 11:41:15 +0000
    DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo.com; s=s2048; t=1488973274; bh=dBoKR3n0yYpzrpZ+bcxP3avnQRc4Or3MGl2sdW0X6zM=; h=Date:From:Reply-To:To:In-Reply-To:References:Subject:From:Subject; b=aaSzXpYniYLlGLxZbcFAaS0A4fD8kPIjjbFDJwdTizBqj/8FxWZ387GFk055MTGav7M0qLTOBlQO3i1rG1KVVE114naXkJ65n9eypiVzlcOBFkLf4RBhWB3jhGZtGuCHaTBtrXL3RgtUpOwqfVgn6oBKesZsDcd65GPL7VgEtlpj0KpHGzn11wfhZW8OgAwRO8IN4pADbFAa345H2X6dkZdbuoJiqqHz0tUTWFZusfevlszLdhblfy40JJRNad0qTk6N87abMS6mQ3s3Ne4K2kSNniJUO1XV3S4gaSCX+WdkJ0Fin37K9vvpn5PhOX3c4ssyd4aRuxwCVuJ/036hfg==
    Received: from [127.0.0.1] by nm34.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 08 Mar 2017 11:41:14 -0000
    Received: from [98.137.12.55] by nm34.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 08 Mar 2017 11:38:13 -0000
    Received: from [98.137.12.205] by tm15.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 08 Mar 2017 11:38:13 -0000
    Received: from [127.0.0.1] by omp1013.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 08 Mar 2017 11:38:13 -0000
    X-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-4
    X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 616938.36655.bm@omp1013.mail.gq1.yahoo.com
    X-YMail-OSG: 1rPsnfAVM1lWZlnrw7gPviOzGFezPXmxB7CcRMnIG9158ac2he2aqLgwdmMM8Lc
     3gPDpuD5c3qfbsexR.ndtqUM2RdqaKj3OLSINrLMPAUff.N3o2wo3oyXzYp6RQg_dfPHKCbZXBIC
     ZxUEJU3w5_OVP5.R7RHztx16eg4k3.JfpxDaVCsxc2FSGXx9RGP5ckRvXczTJ1GJT3xLBdOZfxQw
     kkd.5gi5fPNxsx_sN8o7EXZxq6wLQ3of3cufKeOGQus8m_k0OVFTjYMUGk7orYYyU54wW4aePA5b
     ikhkLap3vKkXsPvpNn9HIXm_Tz0zXZ5iiQeFEFvByOq6agWbu86.sl0MKlVBRfU6lHXHKoknPGhi
     iAe96ygGmP34uapD3r0k0j7ccS0bcnvhUnFpGoLCg0j2jZR5hZZ6fo_A6WcB8RlG_p9YQKfoc1xz
     ZUpu9.SB3XwAuzgYhLRYMWHSJLw7KWbsM_dTTtxXgc77qwNsinfPpW0onYi4FY9Ve3uHMD_M_LFZ
     xjevZ6gW.zKlMBKDFZeY.wXx55bPEtn._5Q--
    Received: from jws300030.mail.gq1.yahoo.com by sendmailws120.mail.gq1.yahoo.com; Wed, 08 Mar 2017 11:38:13 +0000; 1488973093.189
    Date: Wed, 8 Mar 2017 11:38:12 +0000 (UTC)
    From: sanjiv kumar <sanjivrec@yahoo.com>
    Reply-To: sanjiv kumar <sanjivrec@yahoo.com>
    To: "careers@affineanalytics.com" <careers@affineanalytics.com>
    Message-ID: <1219263704.1501133.1488973092883@mail.yahoo.com>
    In-Reply-To: <2063540309.1526520.1488972645785@mail.yahoo.com>
    References: <CAHj72NKfuWpJVyq_gH37fz684mC0sbtU3fCjiOABPAQ26Wnaig@mail.gmail.com> <1958069473.8483966.1484753398404@mail.yahoo.com> <1017720153.1387419.1488959974905@mail.yahoo.com> <2063540309.1526520.1488972645785@mail.yahoo.com>
    Subject: cv for spark+scala
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_Part_1501132_2142304.1488973092883"
    Content-Length: 61596
    Return-Path: sanjivrec@yahoo.com
    X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: a4cc7fba-4f4e-4bcb-b136-08d466180857
    X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
    X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 9be81a95-7870-42f4-bb8d-a44ada88130a:0
    X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
    X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: CIP:98.136.216.141;IPV:NLI;CTRY:US;EFV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;SFS:(6009001)(8196002)(3000300001)(438002)(199003)(189002)(73972006)(21490400002)(43066003)(83332001)(512874002)(50986999)(4110100001)(76176999)(88526003)(16003)(54356999)(956001)(2501003)(189998001)(34766002)(34756002)(86152003)(80022004)(85226003)(81542999)(4610100001)(2860700002)(5000100001)(1096003)(1730700003)(8676002)(3450700001)(42186005)(93886004)(87572001)(7596002)(2476003)(7036003)(568964002)(82202002)(5640700003)(2950100002)(86362001)(110136004)(2351001)(5890100001)(87436003)(356003)(106466001)(84326002)(564344004)(6916009)(7636002)(5660300001)(62882003)(37276004)(71996002);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:1;SRVR:PS1PR01MB0987;H:nm34-vm2.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com;FPR:;SPF:Pass;MLV:sfv;A:1;MX:1;LANG:en;
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;SG2APC01FT061;1: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
    X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: a4cc7fba-4f4e-4bcb-b136-08d466180857
    X-DkimResult-Test: Passed
    X-Microsoft-Antispam: UriScan:;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(22001)(81800161)(8251501002)(3001016)(3010002)(71702078);SRVR:PS1PR01MB0987;
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;PS1PR01MB0987;3:xoCJ5PXIts8QpderPflFcT5PVhTbHfoys2KF0Vmcg4/PzRIzXSlNolvhsisScbT7dqKynC2gesgW/aacqF/+Xk6mhMuA5syRxOwMcVNlFHFdRHCHPhGLbIQi52UYeijKWAb1aWGSJ5kAE/SsjgzwK6qbgn00fyOByiRCFaenLSb6oJFQARSGckrmWnh6NXYoSRs2AcgqK3zukQcbIEI/aAQDwed8LNa83B7WmZTtZMAvQ+R5/iusuKguqQMjZHP/kcJxIw0yZ0P4tVotvhetJs8SHKyqWg1CSeLmE8hWlFYTZrl7oNNUjXFVl8wZLDxAnm8H1csq3+7N2DY/BQOl+ssq6QULWYWNrGLwORsNVU3f7dL0S/PGg4JbnNWpnZxOdcMBQXBgc8JG/uVBhGUj6E9L5TGblt5OUvJnqbo+9FTw2dPVI+wKJxl1wLtFiwP5LLUpr64lrJAdbVPnN6EaymQMTZUH5dI3a0nQaQ/lhGQ=
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;PS1PR01MB0987;25: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;31:jQTDh7LUbjK7utWdpEv/0FEuRUgZlkcPa599EN1Y6Dkxkm5bsjYmT+vrVlQ8kAfjdfAmgl1VlecClhoarcIXrF4nb7vR1HOT6q5d7CppJ0ZCbyy5YpPDL2N3lKFuwI+6OU00pQB9Vm3SauZKsgv+2jp+W44Xv0fYXvrE1+FoRek1LVouY3PH3onUHYfb/C6u4oY5IeTBlnFKkBdhUCGRq46zKuPeQwriNtHHgSSkoPfnvhSNur9BUliPyx6mmGG+R2V3uDMYGhg5FqrIWH+y+FnkQkRty/22vrozLP5P3mW8MEPAmBLkAJiut0r+NkOE+r/Hmv0QlzyE/QKUXabnax8lGN5UX4gwCtFdXPfOqFo=
    X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Service: 1.0
    X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-Test: UriScan:(201166117486090);
    X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(102415395)(9101531078)(601004)(2401047)(7630418)(13016025)(13018025)(8121501046)(7631346)(7632307)(7633261)(9101536074)(10201501046)(3002001);SRVR:PS1PR01MB0987;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:PS1PR01MB0987;
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;PS1PR01MB0987;4: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
    X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 1
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: =?us-ascii?Q?1;PS1PR01MB0987;23:b/vRAY/FEWwW0lgZHyc4R5WXjwvLQ9gbGKlhIT0Sk?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?iO7lLPIdSCwyQ0Qhv76qlBwJxtmyRClFHjRips+ya0B1hR87VEP1/KHW2nKm?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?0Ji3NWErE2h9ARPLIRhHz3EOU+Fkyj11fUsW+ghyae915IADW7QCyBXg1geZ?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?HVDxuIu2T4vcqrBTdSNzkdGxgISVCnvHidaiVmO9e1E5nU/EoCp3Cc0m7OZT?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?5yVwLMSQJDLrd1hzCw01z1kZP0IofgL+stwJOGPz81SAdNJpoqoUojD+hj8J?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?zd7GHhZ99l2+t7FFGvvWzdqVjCwJTxXMkXDEj8uSf2WBQjSoa9WCRGQBl1KV?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?VzaOyPWf640p/oa33qmf41DMzE6UJ5156InG8jBnCKBQXIW95/MfnDxb4+Ac?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?a13AYlNtQj/f1vOe4N9rmeShutG9EuCApIF1tu/x2sDqTPjoin9yBWJTkjO9?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?XeyvuulwCJzCT9ejhLYN9Rr7dh3fcMcXlU5bz7cfaALzpGBcit5S11Mhr/04?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?2Tn05lz0BJc87T1hKvIWTBxZDsavGM0WVozzdgm7VYpsJqfoZAJ0+V4vgRA+?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?6ERJeAN7Z1w0++f5I6upFk3nUO1EKd3i3Wo8aDvV9tA1dm9hyarNaZeGMzUr?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?4+l/sqpjGcWOwPC1cyHZNt0ujYHX9ZGiDujEb8hJvwsWxbpvcBLpUL0TMi0a?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?tx9AiavHI0frsYKjSUWEd2pHgi8pJdQIpfjJj6Xgjd7Iwq7hS4xHk2cotNH4?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?HjHwwqd4am6TQQsgDTvG+5pAMOY1uiqAEJmVh+OQ+zEXEK/EGM1Rs66JHKko?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?1G7y+eyHnOr6fU56qfcfTA4/c0u5WnDS1n3gOOKAeV6V/nx1SiSrjmmdkX56?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?jVSqywevsK9ueeMa1vgvdILVXqhgYpY9y93D1wJ4Q2wFBpVkUjm0ic1g7U4w?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?CgumyhuSiKOlbOAVnXgId2QeZhywrp9PDwp9NsZHpgdDMSrp7fca+tbwnRmH?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?6TgajjcUR+2A+jaHS+VKT4+FZg621BVArr3Vmi5I6GOTcs8qyDA8GKKs50jK?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?qzDryb8mg4pYvHEx7qlu1QqcdXoYpn8Crsw1XTOhbfXJItoyr7X7mJNjkJBN?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?0ZQH8181y3S9joM+kXbJfReVu5tPEmWVWhOvJvKVi1vhiQ+pOnNnFLpyRnFp?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?baS5sWwa+4EsWmhQPluH4fH+7WqivD1/xbEn9XY2JIuPNFIA/xtKeKIIWVMr?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?5IXKK/XcHottEu52yrdfCPE7LlIEanoCPDHWM8yI0gqcd6o0WSGFhgpgxxph?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?nRUBkKYeyCH++9M6WRU0wpfGhYKgLFGTKMlD+oCJ3Irju6vl+60bQbVt6e6j?=
     =?us-ascii?Q?7ji/JxPRvkr3gBwSYZc4dJB83s=3D?=
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;PS1PR01MB0987;6:5qiWb1YG9Adk994ko+3yh3oBV/rBsB9v3/EGU8lJ+RSvyvWkmdifXX0ESuYtKHGCRByUZfhLxZlmLvIZLDFFNXm73K288WC8qHeD8J3DCQ+MF8O/awrq8jty8X+zI2TJQKKUO1Hx4URaBrPFlaYfzdHB2EwC8ueRVCHBxrd+rjgx82fVG7wpR5pmcxV7cTSBo3s+s0usvq23uDQ2TEuk4itohvrPJjc0i1AT0vr/5itMb9mFpH+ZrhKD4BflGn4yRkGdq6fJIQYmTy758AVNMMhwj4jExjU5JvyvAzyeA+4//Fbp3Lan9EonI1L6bqRfg03g/AXMDQIiVy02iQSoQaC0Uom79yHMb1/zrGnwt92c8DpS6VJFkr9YThf5ZV7seugg3M8qis7yoXeFKl7m4YCeT9fSK8F1keA8RyxLG1Q=;5:SWmsTmsQAv+C2F1FlhOmBPo5ifDyomQSJG/tZldfClBj5VE7UYwuIWt8AMNUfmUbvS3/BWL6DuFxd74PxSUapJP9GQMUJu9WqY7arnB82EOmshGbFJ4S5ajtoevWGbcNYQCbb5zv2FjK+gTCSsuPN//unro7ftCo8zqdQsbLCLE=;24:ofDtEiqoNw62Sdcwjr5LX+U9itLyfdkvQAyJCL7Lr8lAsX1JdRkikRJ7ZbYkBOyYjNUEKcVKViihckOMmrlGFF2Yp3MNsFpKukEv5FYHBOQ=
    SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:99
    SpamDiagnosticMetadata: NSPM
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;PS1PR01MB0987;7:0JxZqVV2BiqN2K6eHAG2V49XW2ABmF37/+1O8pfvpGhDpSB0U8YZeY85DmewDY3lgeRG2qVBiX4IyCsNvfBehEWtX6QfaesVI3tsJAixqdDk5buDzJ+FZqVFWA8xIaoGVff13aVkUoi6y0p/rcTDOE7Zn6jCv6kpWvKf6ZL6Mis7UTpRefH9CK54jD2v/K37TlrhwUtYWG4ZWvi0XH//Xl5LNe6b4mhLi4M4ETyZfEvFOr5m9arG57vLK+Ejq3Gdkrhj4gJ7tDkQ0nGTvi/SqLTCR09DizpAiLz1FT3C8Mj1zKOjoXH9/aexpREsxsWIHTtn+xB+8ebcnYmcMDDktSZgCXi2Hn1Y4Raek6MmHzSk6r2jyKhE7hEIX9sVbDcu
    X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 08 Mar 2017 11:41:15.8482
     (UTC)
    X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 9be81a95-7870-42f4-bb8d-a44ada88130a
    X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
    X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: PS1PR01MB0987
    X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: SG2APC01FT061.eop-APC01.prod.protection.outlook.com
    X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
    X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:05.7287080
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
        1;KL1PR01MB0984;27:kngpZulfR/DkyZnS+YcM/0dhMkFd0UscG/q4HI6HHMEog7KrGPdg3vNXzVvQIzW6qjLf1ZdakMOtqczk880ZUvFZoSM9VnaAMZ34gxPAoY0wCVQZO3GxEovd8zGiKFT7w/Cik8W6dH2npkdNT/vSBg==
    X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
        ex:0;auth:0;dest:I;ENG:(20160514016)(520000050)(520011016)(750028);
    MIME-Version: 1.0

    ------=_Part_1501132_2142304.1488973092883
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
        boundary="----=_Part_1501131_1600509571.1488973092881"
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
        1;KL1PR01MB0984;27:kngpZulfR/DkyZnS+YcM/0dhMkFd0UscG/q4HI6HHMEog7KrGPdg3vNXzVvQIzW6qjLf1ZdakMOtqczk880ZUvFZoSM9VnaAMZ34gxPAoY0wCVQZO3GxEovd8zGiKFT7w/Cik8W6dH2npkdNT/vSBg==
    X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
        ex:0;auth:0;dest:I;ENG:(20160514016)(520000050)(520011016)(750028);

    ------=_Part_1501131_1600509571.1488973092881
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
        1;KL1PR01MB0984;27:kngpZulfR/DkyZnS+YcM/0dhMkFd0UscG/q4HI6HHMEog7KrGPdg3vNXzVvQIzW6qjLf1ZdakMOtqczk880ZUvFZoSM9VnaAMZ34gxPAoY0wCVQZO3GxEovd8zGiKFT7w/Cik8W6dH2npkdNT/vSBg==
    X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
        ex:0;auth:0;dest:I;ENG:(20160514016)(520000050)(520011016)(750028);



       =C2=A0=20


       =C2=A0=C2=A0=20
    Hi=20
    Please find my cv for the opening in big data hadoop.Please feel free to ca=
    ll me if require any more information.
    ThanksSanjiv9731378812

      =20

      =20
    ------=_Part_1501131_1600509571.1488973092881
    Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
        1;KL1PR01MB0984;27:kngpZulfR/DkyZnS+YcM/0dhMkFd0UscG/q4HI6HHMEog7KrGPdg3vNXzVvQIzW6qjLf1ZdakMOtqczk880ZUvFZoSM9VnaAMZ34gxPAoY0wCVQZO3GxEovd8zGiKFT7w/Cik8W6dH2npkdNT/vSBg==
    X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
        ex:0;auth:0;dest:I;ENG:(20160514016)(520000050)(520011016)(750028);

    <html><head>
    <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8"></=
    head><body><div style=3D"color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:Hel=
    veticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;fon=
    t-size:12px"><div><span></span></div><div class=3D"qtdSeparateBR"><br><br><=
    /div><div class=3D"yahoo_quoted" id=3D"yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_2883=
    9" style=3D"display: block;">  <div id=3D"yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_2=
    8838" style=3D"font-family: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial=
    , Lucida Grande, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"> <div id=3D"yui_3_16_0_ym19_=
    1_1488954620729_28837" style=3D"font-family: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue,=
     Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;"> <div id=3D=
    "yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_28836" dir=3D"ltr">&nbsp;<font id=3D"yui_3=
    _16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_28840" face=3D"Arial" size=3D"2"> </font><br></d=
    iv><div class=3D"y_msg_container" id=3D"yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_288=
    41"><div id=3D"yiv1575164081"><div id=3D"yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_28=
    844"><div id=3D"yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_28843" style=3D"color: rgb(=
    0, 0, 0); font-family: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Luc=
    ida Grande, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 25=
    5);"><div><span></span></div><div class=3D"yiv1575164081qtdSeparateBR" id=
    =3D"yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_28842"><br clear=3D"none"><br clear=3D"=
    none"></div><div class=3D"yiv1575164081yahoo_quoted" id=3D"yiv1575164081yui=
    _3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_26789" style=3D"display: block;">  <div id=3D"=
    yiv1575164081yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_26788" style=3D"font-family: H=
    elveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif; =
    font-size: 12px;"> <div id=3D"yiv1575164081yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_=
    26787" style=3D"font-family: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Aria=
    l, Lucida Grande, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;"> <div id=3D"yiv1575164081yu=
    i_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_26786" dir=3D"ltr">&nbsp;<font id=3D"yiv15751=
    64081yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_26807" face=3D"Arial" size=3D"2">&nbsp=
    ;</font></div> <div class=3D"yiv1575164081y_msg_container" id=3D"yiv1575164=
    081yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_26816"><br clear=3D"none"><div id=3D"yiv=
    1575164081"><div id=3D"yiv1575164081yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_26827">=
    <div id=3D"yiv1575164081yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_26826" style=3D"col=
    or: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Ar=
    ial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; background-color: rgb(255,=
     255, 255);"><div id=3D"yiv1575164081yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_26825"=
    >Hi </div><div class=3D"yiv1575164081yqt9579761851" id=3D"yiv1575164081yqtf=
    d93061"><div id=3D"yiv1575164081yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_26838"><br =
    clear=3D"none"></div><div id=3D"yiv1575164081yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_148895462072=
    9_26839" dir=3D"ltr">Please find my cv for the opening in big data hadoop.P=
    lease feel free to call me if require any more information.</div><div class=
    =3D"yiv1575164081yqt9811900359" id=3D"yiv1575164081yqtfd37702"><div id=3D"y=
    iv1575164081yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_17957" dir=3D"ltr"><br clear=3D=
    "none"></div><div id=3D"yiv1575164081yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1488954620729_26840"=
     dir=3D"ltr">Thanks</div><div dir=3D"ltr">Sanjiv</div><div dir=3D"ltr">9731=
    378812</div></div></div></div></div></div><div class=3D"yiv1575164081yqt957=
    9761851" id=3D"yiv1575164081yqtfd43793"><br clear=3D"none"><br clear=3D"non=
    e"></div></div><div class=3D"yiv1575164081yqt9579761851" id=3D"yiv157516408=
    1yqtfd32754"> </div></div><div class=3D"yiv1575164081yqt9579761851" id=3D"y=
    iv1575164081yqtfd22999"> </div></div><div class=3D"yiv1575164081yqt95797618=
    51" id=3D"yiv1575164081yqtfd76439">  </div></div></div></div></div><br><br>=
    </div> </div> </div>  </div></div></body></html>=

    ------=_Part_1501131_1600509571.1488973092881--

    ------=_Part_1501132_2142304.1488973092883
    Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Sanjiv_HADOOP_12.doc.docx"
    Content-ID: <901edec0-0739-f50e-aec8-4be8d9502523@yahoo.com>
    X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
        1;KL1PR01MB0984;27:kngpZulfR/DkyZnS+YcM/0dhMkFd0UscG/q4HI6HHMEog7KrGPdg3vNXzVvQIzW6qjLf1ZdakMOtqczk880ZUvFZoSM9VnaAMZ34gxPAoY0wCVQZO3GxEovd8zGiKFT7w/Cik8W6dH2npkdNT/vSBg==
    X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
        ex:0;auth:0;dest:I;ENG:(20160514016)(520000050)(520011016)(750028);



    ------=_Part_1501132_2142304.1488973092883--
```

Comment: Is it a text/plain message?  Use `msg.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt"));` and then post the content of the msg.txt file.

Comment: Yes it text/plain.   below is the content of text file "msg.txt"                                                                                           Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
 =C2=A0=20
   =C2=A0=C2=A0=20
Hi=20
Please find my cv for the opening in big data hadoop.Please feel free to ca=
ll me if require any more information.
ThanksSanjiv9731378812

  =20

  =20
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Comment: You need to add the message content to your original post and make sure it is formatted correctly, otherwise it's impossible to see if there are any newlines in the message content.

Comment: Actual content sent from yahoo is as below.
Hi

Please find my cv for the opening in big data hadoop.Please feel free to call me if require any more information.

Thanks
Sanjiv
9731378812                                                                               But we are getting as below.  =C2=A0=20 =C2=A0=C2=A0=20 Hi=20 Please find my cv for the opening in big data hadoop.Please feel free to ca= ll me if require any more information. ThanksSanjiv9731378812 =20 =20

Comment: You didn't understand.  Go back to the top and edit your original post.  Add the content from msg.txt.  Make sure it looks exactly like it does in msg.txt.  When you add it as a comment, all the lines just run together and you can't see where the new lines are in the original data.

Comment: Its not allowing to add more than 30000 chars ,the actual content having 76k chars.

Comment: There's definitely some newlines in the text/plain content, although it looks like the text/plain content was converted from the text/html content and some of the formatting is messed up.  If you're calling getContent on the text/plain part and it's returning you a String without any newlines, then something else is going wrong.  Can you post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) when you access this data?  (You can delete all those Microsoft Exchange headers at the top if you need more space.)

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to see the code you're using to access the message data.  Or, try using the [JavaMail msgshow.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) to read the message and see what it shows.